# sql query to get data greater than everyday at particular time

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic, sysdatetime

I want all records which exist than particular date timestamp and the table create_datetime column.

When this query is run, it should provide all the records for the day greater than create_datetime with a particular 18:00:00

Comment: Can you provide example table definition with some test data input and your expected output?

Comment: `select * from table where create_date_time > to_date('date_here'||18:00:00, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss';` where `date_here` is your input date in format `dd-mon-yyyy`. This question is basic.

Answer (score 0):

Your question text is a bit chopped up but what I think is you want every record where the time element of the `create_date` is after 18:00.  If so, this query will get that.  It uses the date format mask `SSSSS` which returns date as the number of seconds after midnight.

```
select * from your_table
where to_number(to_char(create_date, 'SSSSS')) >= (18 * (60*60))
and some_other_date >= trunc(sysdate)
```

The other part of that query is a wild guess, because like I said, your question has been lost in translation.  I have plumped for "records where some other date column has been set  to today's date".